# IronPython Windows forms, passing variables in python

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm new to IronPython and trying to create a simple application with windows forms that converts a fixed fielded file to a delimited file.

I've created a form with three buttons.

The first is to select the file to be converted. 
The second is to select a file with a the layout of the first file. 
The third is a 'submit' button to send the file names of the two files above to the python function that will convert the file.

The first two buttons work fine. My problem is passing the file names to the 'button_submitPressed' function. I tried to make FILENAME and LAYOUT global variables (I've tried it inside and outside of the 'HelloWorldForm' class but neither are working).

What do I have to do to pass variables that I collect in button events to another function?

When I run this, when I click on the submit button (after clicking the first two and selecting the filename and layout) I get the error:

```
IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: global name 'FILENAME' is not defined
```

Thanks.

```
class HelloWorldForm(Form):
    FILENAME = ''
    LAYOUT = ''
    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'ff2delim'

        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Text = "Convert fixed legnth file to delimited"
        self.label.Location = Point(50, 50)
        self.label.Height = 30
        self.label.Width = 200

        self.count = 0

        button = Button()
        button.Text = "File name"
        button.Location = Point(50, 100)

        button.Click += self.buttonPressed

        button2 = Button()
        button2.Text = "Layout"
        button2.Location = Point(50, 130)

        button2.Click += self.button2Pressed

        button_submit = Button()
        button_submit.Text = "Convert"
        button_submit.Location = Point(50, 190)

        button_submit.Click += self.button_submitPressed

        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.Controls.Add(button)
        self.Controls.Add(button2)
        self.Controls.Add(button_submit)


    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        dialogf = OpenFileDialog()
        if dialogf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK:
            FILENAME = dialogf.FileName
            print "FILENAME: " + FILENAME 
            self.label_filename = Label()
            self.label_filename.Text = FILENAME
            self.label_filename.Location = Point(140, 105)
            self.label_filename.Height = 30
            self.label_filename.Width = 200    
            self.Controls.Add(self.label_filename) 
        else:
            print "No file selected"

    def button2Pressed(self, sender, args):
        dialogl = OpenFileDialog()
        if dialogl.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK:
            LAYOUT = dialogl.FileName
            print "LAYOUT: " + LAYOUT 
            self.label_layout = Label()
            self.label_layout.Text = LAYOUT
            self.label_layout.Location = Point(140, 135)
            self.label_layout.Height = 30
            self.label_layout.Width = 200    
            self.Controls.Add(self.label_layout) 
        else:
            print "No file selected"

    def button_submitPressed(self, sender, args):
        convert(FILENAME,LAYOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by putting in a global variable in the first two button handlers.

```
def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
    global FILENAME
    dialogf = OpenFileDialog()
    if dialogf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK:
        FILENAME = dialogf.FileName
        print "FILENAME: ",FILENAME
    ...

def button2Pressed(self, sender, args):
    global LAYOUT
    dialogl = OpenFileDialog()
    if dialogl.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK:
        LAYOUT = dialogl.FileName
        print "LAYOUT: " + dialogl.FileName
    ...
```

Then in the third button handler:

```
def button_submitPressed(self, sender, args):
    print "FILENAME SUB: ",FILENAME
    print "LAYOUT SUB: ",LAYOUT
    convert(FILENAME,LAYOUT)
```

The third button handler then successfully calls the convert function.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, OP's code would have worked if he accessed his class level constants through the class:

```
def button_submitPressed(self, sender, args):
    convert(self.FILENAME,self.LAYOUT)
```